# modification ideas for improving FCN and R-CNN Deep learning models

Tags: deep-learning

I am a new developer of the standard deep learning convolutional model R-CNN and FCN.

I would like to modify this built-in architecture and improve its performance. any idea of how to change the architecture in a way that can gif better segmentation accuracy?

Comment: This is quite a vague question for SO, and I suspect you could write a lecture series on the topic! Have a look at the [Data Science Stack Exchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) which is aimed at Machine Learning topics :)

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the ROI Align layer might be a nice first step. Specifically changing how you interpolate pixel values that are split the ROI Align division lines. Although ROI Align likely has very optimal performance compared to crude alignment.

You could also use something fancier than max pooling to develop the initial feature maps, such as fo-pooling.